# android.support.transition.TransitionSet cannot be cast to android.transition.Transition

Tags: android, shared-element-transition

I am trying some shared element transition, and I got this error  that I don't know how to handle.

My transition is between two fragments, I clicked on a recycleView item and I open a new fragment, and I want to share a imageview between this two fragments.

I followed this exact steps > http://mikescamell.com/shared-element-transitions-part-4-recyclerview/ <  (there is a working sample at the end of the article).

Any help?

Comment: the first comes from `support` library, the second doesnt - check the inheritance structure

Comment: what I should exactly looking for?

Comment: for a base class for `android.support.transition.TransitionSet` - its in the javadocs

Comment: but I dont have android.support.transition.TransitionSet import in my project. I verified, both of my fragments extend the supoort.v4.fragment.. So, what exactly I have to check?

Comment: so post the stack trace and the code where your app crashes

Comment: change import android.support.transition.TransitionInflater to import android.transition.TransitionInflater  . I had the same issue :(